# Numpy: Iterate multiplication of 3D array by 1D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 3D array (4,3,3) in which I would like to iteratively multiply with a 1D array (t variable) and sum to end up with an array (A) that is a summation of the four 3,3 arrays
I'm unsure on how I should be assigning indexes or how and if I should be using  np.ndenumerate

Thanks

```
import numpy as np
import math

#Enter material constants for calculation of stiffness matrix
E1 = 20    
E2 = 1.2    
G12 = 0.8    
v12=0.25    
v21=(v12/E1)*E2
theta = np.array([30,-30,-30,30])   
deg = ((math.pi*theta/180))
k = len(theta)  #number of layers
t = np.array([0.005,0.005,0.005,0.005])

#Calculation of Q Values

Q11 = 1
Q12 = 2
Q21 = 3
Q22 = 4
Q66 = 5

Qbar = np.zeros((len(theta),3,3),order='F')  

#CALCULATING THE VALUES OF THE QBAR MATRIX
for i, x in np.ndenumerate(deg):

    m= np.cos(x)  #sin of rotated lamina
    n= np.sin(x)   #cos of rotated lamina
    
    Qbar11=Q11*3
    Qbar12=Q22*4
    Qbar16=Q16*4
    Qbar21 = Qbar12
    Qbar22=Q22*1
    Qbar26=Q66*2
    Qbar66=Q12*3

    
    Qbar[i] = np.array([[Qbar11, Qbar12, Qbar16], [Qbar21, Qbar22, Qbar26], [Qbar16, Qbar26, Qbar66]], order = 'F')

print(Qbar)

A = np.zeros((3,3))

for i in np.nditer(t):
    A[i]=Qbar[i]*t[i]
    A=sum(A[i])
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to multiply `Qbar` and `t` over the first axis, and then summing the result over the first axis (which results in an array of shape `(3, 3)`).

I created random arrays to make the code minimal:

```py
import numpy as np

Qbar = np.random.randint(2, size=(4, 3, 3))
t = np.arange(4)

A = (Qbar * t[:, None, None]).sum(axis=0)
```

`t[:, None, None]` will create two new dimensions so that the shape becomes `(4, 1, 1)`, which can be multiplied to `Qbar` element-wise. Then we just have to sum over the first axis.

NB: `A = np.tensordot(t, Qbar, axes=([0],[0]))` also works and can be faster for larger dimensions, but for the dimensions you provided I prefer the first solution.

Comment: Worked perfectly, code is much simpler than any others for the same solver. Much appreciated!